# Problem displaying an item according to the url - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a question. I have a component that when entering /category/:categoryId is rendered doing a fecth to "api url + categoryId". My problem is that if I change from one category to another the page only changes if the useEffect is executed infinitely which generates problems to the view as seen below. How can I make it run once and when I change from /category/1 to /category/2 the useEffect is executed correctly?

```js
const Categories = () => {
    let [producto, productos] = useState([]);
    const { categoryId } = useParams();

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('https://fakestoreapi.com/products/category/' + categoryId)
            .then(res=>res.json())
            .then(data=>productos(data))
    },[]);

    console.log(producto)

    return(
        <div className="container">
            {producto.map((p) => (
                <Producto
                    title={p.title}
                    price={p.price}
                    description={p.description}
                    image={p.image}
                    key={p.id}
                    id={p.id}
                />
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Categories;
```

My router file:

```js
<Route path="/category/:categoryId" component={Categories} />
```

This is the problem that is generated, there comes a time when a fetch is made to a previously requested category and then the new requested category is executed.

[See my problem in video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ac69PrzhQJg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply add `categoryId` to `useEffect` array argument. Function inside the `useEffect` is called, only when `categoryId` changes

```
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('https://fakestoreapi.com/products/category/' + categoryId)
            .then(res=>res.json())
            .then(data=>productos(data))
    },[categoryId]);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can not edit `producto` directly, you should use productos :

```
const Categories = () => {
    let [producto, productos] = useState([]);
    const { categoryId } = useParams();

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('https://fakestoreapi.com/products/category/' + categoryId)
            .then(res=>res.json())
            .then(data=>productos(data))
    },[]);

    console.log(producto)

    return(
        <div className="container">
            {producto && producto.map((p) => (
                <Producto
                    title={p.title}
                    price={p.price}
                    description={p.description}
                    image={p.image}
                    key={p.id}
                    id={p.id}
                />
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Categories;
```

Comment: I know, I forgot to remove "product = [];". I was just testing. It still doesn't work anyway. If i remove [] from useEffect it updates when I change from one category to another but when I do it repeatedly it starts to happen what is shown in the video. And if I leave the [] in useEffect it only updates the first time because when I change the url it doesn't update!